# rails 3.0 routing - redirect globbed route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes file we originally had this rout set up:

```
  match '/search/*tag' => 'search#search'
```

We now want to remove the word 'search' from the url. So I added a new route:

```
match '/*tag' => 'search#search'
```

That all works beautifully. We wanted to update the old route to redirect to the new one to keep seo and bookmarks working.

```
 match '/search/*tag' => redirect {|params| "/#{params[:tag]}"}
```

However this is pluralizing the term.

```
Input url: www.fubar.com/search/work
Becomes:   www.fubar.com/works
```

What is causing this and how do I stop it from pluralizing the tag?

Might be relevant: We need to use /*tag instead of /:tag because we sometimes have a list of tags. I.e. www.fubar.com/work/web/video

Answer (score 1):

Turns out everything worked once I cleared my cache. Browsers remember 301 redirects (and I forgot that and was apparently kept serving a previous broken redirect.

```
match '/search/*tag' => redirect { |params| "/#{params[:tag]}" }
match '/*tag' => 'search#search'
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can recommend is stuffing a Rails.logger.debug{ params.inspect } inside the block to redirect.  That'd at least give you a start on debugging it.  Rails routing can be tricky and brittle when you stray from the happy path, and knowing whether the issue is in the recognition (i.e. that the match for *tags is being pluralized) or in routing (that the result from the redirection is being pluralized) would be the first place to look.

Comment: Running  Rails.logger.debug{ params.inspect } in the block I get {:tag=>"work"} as the output for the URL www.fubar.com/search/work